Desperate for help!
I am taking over maintaining a website that was done in Craft CMS by a different webdeveloper (he has stoppd responding to the client). I have the login info for admin and when I go to the dashboard, when I click Entries, nothing shows up in the list. I don't know if I am looking in the wrong place. There is an error message at the top:
Warning: Declaration of craft\helpers\FileHelper::getExtensionByMimeType($mimeType): string should be compatible with yii\helpers\BaseFileHelper::getExtensionByMimeType($mimeType, $preferShort = false, $magicFile = NULL) in /var/www/milne-fruit-craft-stage/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/FileHelper.php on line 719
The IT department at the company is trying to get access to the AWS hosting account the previous designer set up, since they don't have the login credentials for it.
Would this server error explain why I can't see the entries? Any insight would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Hi Beth, which version of Craft are you running? I think it's likely you'll need to update the site using composer/SSH.

It looks like it's PRO 3.7.26
If I try to update it and it breaks anything, we don't have server/hosting account access yet to go in and try to fix it.
Do you know of a way to back up the site? I'm assuming a plugin, but the plugin store won't load, so I'm thinking I'm out of luck until we can access the server.

Yeah, you will need as a minimum I think. It should just be a case of updating the Craft version in your composer.json to 3.9.14 (the latest version) and running composer update via SSH. Before that, you can try running php craft db/backup to take a backup.

My general approach to a situation like this is to get it running locally as best you can and then try to deal with the production server. To start, at a minimum, you'll want a database backup. I haven't used Craft 3 in a while, but in Craft 4 and 5, there is a Utilities menu with a Database Backup area which has an option to download a copy of the database to your browser. If that works, you're a whole lot closer to getting the site fixed.
